# How to run code during app uninstall in flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to run code to delete files created on local storage when my flutter app is uninstalled. How can I do the same? Is there any event to handle this? If not, how can I clean up the images generated?I don't see any reference online for this.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that any app resources including files are deleted along with the app. I cannot quote anything so this is a comment, but I have seen this written somewhere...

Comment: No, it doesn't it. I have tried it. Images that were generated, for example through a qr br flutter package as images and saved to gallery, don't get deleted automatically and become orphans when app is uninstalled. Only if images are provisioned as part of app, it gets deleted

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving images to users gallery, that image is no longer the domain of your app, in any way shape or form. If you create a gallery within your app this would be different, also, a gallery within your app would in fact be deleted along with any other memory your app uses. I highly doubt you could access users gallery & delete images even with users permission.

Possible backend server solution: [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/30025)

[This](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/13846) indicates this is not possible as per below:

> All of your app's files are deleted by the OS when the user deletes
> the app. If Apple wanted developers to have that capability, we would
> have that capability
>
> You could make a case for needing to know the app is deleted if you
> are storing stuff on the server side. Currently from the server's
> point of view there's no way to know whether the app was deleted or
> the user just stopped using it. But locally stored files are not an
> issue.

I am also looking for a solution to this & I think server logic will get it done.
Must be some sort of logic possible to discover server side if user is GONE!